# c# Mysql query check

Tags: c#, mysql

so guys i was trying to validate data from MySQL query against  some text but only when the validation is true the code is fine otherwise the code down the else if statement not works

```
   while (rdr.Read())
 { 
    string realUsername = Convert.ToString(rdr["username"]);
    string realPassword = Convert.ToString(rdr["pass"]);
    if (realUsername == txtBoxUserName.Text.Trim() && realPassword == txtBoxPassWord.Text.Trim())
     {
       MessageBox.Show("OK!");
     }

    else
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Error");
                        
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should never store passwords as plaintext - or even encrypted - in your database.  They should be salted and hashed.

Comment: it's for testing purpose

Comment: why you don't use a command to compare into database , for example, "select count(id) from users where user= @user and password=@password" this use sql parameters and prevent  SQL injection , then on reader verify if the value of rdr[0] is  > 0

Comment: can you please explain more i am new to c# basically i used to the simplicity of python

Comment: @Ali i posted an answer

Comment: @Ali, if the answare help ypu, please mark is correct answare. thanks

Answer (score 0):

respect of comments:

```
        // prepare de SQL sentence
        var SQL_string = "SELECT Count(Id) FROM users u WHERE u.user = @USR AND u.password= @PASS;";
        var cnn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("YourConnectionString");
        var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(SQL_string, cnn);

        // You can use parameters to prevent SQL Injection
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USR", txtBoxUserName.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASS", txtBoxPassWord.Text.Trim());

        var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            // Read the returned value
            if ((int)rdr[0] > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OK!"); // When return more than 0 users
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error"); // when not match users
            }
        }
```